# Struts (1) default locale isn't chosen

Tags: struts, locale

In my application user can choose from 2 locales, EN and IT. If the browser uses another language, then the English must be chosen automatically, right?

BUT, here is the problem, that when for example user comes with French browser, he tries to find French in there, but there is no French locales, and he displaying no content on the pages.

So, the question is: What library or process is responding for choosing default locales? maybe my libraries are outdated, or?

Answer (score 0):

> If the browser uses another language, then the English must be chosen automatically, right?

It depends! Struts tries to find the most specific message bundle and then falls back to some defaults (like the default JVM locale or message bundle with no language suffix). [Normally it's something like this](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/util/PropertyMessageResources.html):

```
base + "_" + localeLanguage + "_" + localeCountry + "_" + localeVariant
base + "_" + localeLanguage + "_" + localeCountry
base + "_" + localeLanguage
base + "_" + default locale
base
```

> ... there is no French locales, and he displaying no content on the pages.

That does not seem right; when a message key can't be resolved you either get an exception like: *"Missing message for key "..." in bundle "..." for locale ..."* or you get a result like *"???fr.yourKey???"* for a configuration like `<message-resources ... null="false" />` in your struts-config.xml, so you should see something on the page or at least in the logs.

My suggestion would be to activate the logs for `org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources` and see what it tries to find. Also check your .properties files, maybe your keys are resolved in the default file and they are empty.

As for the process who selects the Locale to use in the current request (apart from what PropertyMessageResources is doing with its operating modes), at some point the 
Struts request processor makes a call to [`org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.SelectLocale`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/chain/commands/servlet/SelectLocale.html) who is responsible for returning the Locale.

This class tries to find a cached Locale inside the session. If it can't find one there it uses the one in the request. If it can't find one there either it finally defaults to the JVM Locale. Your locale is now selected and cached in the session.

This is a Struts class, so you will find it in the struts-core JAR. If you have access to the Struts source code for the specific version you are using, you can have a look yourself at how the Locale is managed; the code using [Globals.LOCALE_KEY](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/Globals.html#LOCALE_KEY) is what you you'll be after.

Comment: You explain what I already know, although my question was different :)

Comment: @Comodore Panamo: I've updated the answer with some details. See if it helps, if not then tell me what kind of answer you are looking for.